# How to free space of an APFS drive in Recovery Mode after deleting folders?

Tags: terminal, mac, big-sur, recovery

I'm trying to reinstall Big Sur on my M1, but it tells me I need an additional 13 GB.

In Recovery Mode, I deleted three folders through the Terminal from the mounted /Data drive, one of 20G, another one of 10G, and another of 14GB.  And still, it says I need 13GB.

I deleted the trash bin in Terminal with `rm -r ~/.Trash/*`, nothing still.

What else should I do? Why doesn't the folder deletion reflect immediately in Recovery Mode? Is it a trash bin issue?

Comment: I believe you need to use tmutil to delete snapshots. However I'm having trouble finding the command to do this. Try searching for how to delete time machine snapshots in big sur and see if you can find something that works.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. tmutil Snapshots. I'll try this https://www.macworld.com/article/231067/how-to-delete-time-machine-snapshots-on-your-mac.html

Comment: Deleting from the shell with `rm` couldn't care less about your trash folder.

Comment: You mean that whatever is deleted with rm in the shell, is destroyed on the spot?